# Adding third party dll in xamarin studio

Tags: android, xamarin

I am new to xamarin I am not finding the correct way to add third party dll to the application. Can some one help me in doing it. I googled a lot but i could not get any source.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just add a reference as you would in any C# project.  What are you trying to add?  You cannot use any arbitrary .NET dll with a Xamarin project.

Comment: I have a dll which is used in a win32 app. I am trying to refer that from the xamarin project

Comment: Use scan.xamarin.com to determine if the dll is compatible with Xamarin.Android

Comment: Unless the library is PCL you will need to compile it for Xamarin.Android target. You can not add a reference to a library that targets .NET.

Answer (score 2):

`Xamarin` is based on `Mono` platform which is created for a cross-platform development. And obviously it has some constraints - you can use **only *mono-libraries* or *PCL* libs**.

Thanks to hard work of Mono community and `Xamarin` there are a lot of popular ported libs that you can download and use in *mono-projects*: [Popular Libraries ported to Mono.](http://mono-project.com/Libraries)

If your lib is not in the list - you'll have to port it by your own: [Guides and howto's available](http://mono-project.com/Moma)

---

To sum up you'll have to port or find existing mono-library and add it into your `Xamarin.Andriod` application.

Comment: Only if the target is iOS or Android. .NET libraries will work on Mono as long as they do not invoke any Win32 specific native libraries. Same goes the other way, Mono libraries invoking native OSX or Linux libraries will not work on Windows but pure Mono libraries should.